# How to append an array to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to append an array **new** to an existing empty array **ra** like this:

```
ra.append(new)
```

However, when I run this code and write **ra**, it looks like this:

```
ra = [array([ 103.290577,  103.312447,  103.371779,  103.376812,  103.38486 ,...]]
```

All of my values are appending correctly and I am getting a 2d array, but there is this string "array" at the beginning of every array inside **ra**.  What is causing this and how can I correct my problem?

I definitely need to use **append** as I need an array of arrays.  My problem is when I write **ra**, I get this string "array(" in front of every new array.  Why is this happening is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `ra.extend(new)` ?
Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

**Edit:** OP's comment: *From what I have read, I thought that extend would add my values, but I would have one long array. I need a 2d array of these values.*

Yes extend() will create one long array from elements of `ra` and `new`.AFAIK no inbuilt function is available for create a 2d array from two 1d arrays. Although if you have all numbers in ra and new, you can use ***numpy*** and use `column_stack` or `vstack` to stack `ra` and `new` together to create a 2d array.

Comment: From what I have read, I thought that extend would add my values, but I would have one long array.  I need a 2d array of these values.

Comment: Thank you.  I was not able to find commands like these through my research.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is when I write ra, I get this string "array(" in front of every new array. Why is this happening is my question.

You do not need to worry about this, it just means that your list was initialized as an array from some import functionality. Not sure what that is without a larger code sample, but it looks like `numpy` or `array`.

If you have used `import array` there is a simple function that turns it back into a list and removed that header: `new_list = new.tolist()`